# pipe in del(... | select(... | ...)) works in v1.6, how to get same result in v1.5?

Tags: json, select, nested, jq

I'm trying to remove some objects based on tags within an array.  I can get it working fine on jqplay.org (v1.6) but is there any way to get the same result in v1.5?  I just get an error `Invalid path expression with result`

The goal is to return the JSON stripped of the top two (`content` and `data`) levels, and with the properties of `notes` stripped out if there isn't a `types` tag starting with 'x' or 'y' for that note.

Here's the v1.6 working example: https://jqplay.org/s/AVpz_IkfJa

There's also this: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1146 but I don't know how (or if it's possible) to apply the workaround for `del()` rather than `path()`, assuming it's the same basic problem.

#### JQ instructions:

```jq
.content.data 
  | del(
  .hits[].doc.notes[] 
    | select
    ( .types 
      | any(startswith("x") or startswith("y")) 
      | not 
    )
  )
```

#### input JSON:

```json
{ 
  "content": { "data": {
   "meta": "stuff",
   "hits": [
    { "doc": 
      {
        "id": "10",
        "notes": {
         "f1": {"name": "F1", "types": ["wwwa", "zzzb"] },
         "f2": {"name": "F2", "types": ["xxxa", "yyya"] }
       }
     },
     "score": "1"
   },
   { "doc": 
    {
      "id": "11",
      "notes": {
       "f1": {"name": "F1", "types": ["wwwa", "zzzb"] },
       "f3": {"name": "F3", "types": ["qzxb", "xxxb"] }
     }
   },
   "score": "2"
 } ] } } }
```

#### Desired result:

```json
{
  "meta": "stuff",
  "hits": [
    {
      "doc": {
        "id": "10",
        "notes": {
          "f2": {"name": "F2", "types": ["xxxa", "yyya"] }
        }
      },
      "score": "1"
    },
    {
      "doc": {
        "id": "11",
        "notes": {
          "f3": {"name": "F3", "types": ["qzxb", "xxxb"] }
        }
      },
      "score": "2"
} ] }
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. I'm pretty much a jq novice. Even if it's not practically do-able in v1.5 at least I won't lose more hours trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

OP back after a few hours - I found something that seems to work, still very interested in any comments / other ways to crack the problem / improvements.

```
.content.data  
  | .hits[].doc.notes |= map (
    if ( .types | any(startswith("x") or startswith("y")))
      then .
      else empty
    end 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a variation of the solution proposed by the OP.  It illustrates how a complex use of `del` can be expressed in a more straightforward and robust way by crafting a suitable helper function.

The relevant helper function in the present case implements the stripping-out requirement:

```
# Input: an object some keys of which are to be removed
def prune:
   to_entries
   | map( select( any(.value.types[]; test("^(x|y)")) ) )
   | from_entries ;
```

The task can now be accomplished using a one-liner:

```
.content.data | .hits |= map( .doc.notes |= prune )
```

### Invocation

With the above jq program in program.jq, a suitable invocation of jq
would look like this:

```
jq -f program.jq input.json
```